# URL redirection having parameters in URL using .htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have a url like this -

```
http://www.xyz.in/zone/zone.php?zone_id=zone_118
```

I need to write rule in .htaccess such that the above url should be executed with below url :

```
http://www.xyz.in/zone/zone/zone_118 OR
http://www.xyz.in/zone/zone_118
```

Any help will be highly useful

I am trying as below but not getting any luck :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} zone_id=$1
 RewriteRule ^zone/zone\.php$ /zone/?zone_id=([^\&\ ]+) [L,R=301]
 Redirect one clean URL to a new clean URL
```

Comment: Please do share your htaccess in your question, thank you

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - Edited my question to include the file

Comment: This is a very straightforward role to write, but your attempt is basically back to front. Have a look at this: [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: @IMSoP Have checked the link but still facing issue. can you please write it for me ?

Comment: Giving you one example, that's basically identical to thousands of examples you could find online, isn't going to help you learn; next time you need a rule, you'll be back with another question, with a few words changed. If you're here to learn, you need to do more than "check the link"; you need to really try to understand it. If you're here to have other people write code to order, pay someone some money instead.

Comment: @IMSOP is right, you have your RewriteRule quite wrong, check [this very nice explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20563773/145939) about how mod_rewrite works